# How to get 2 sub strings as 2 columns from single column of table

Tags: sql-server, msbi

[{"key":"Mobile","value":"9100617634"},{"key":"Email","value":"balajirao1@ziaff.in"}]

The above one represents the value in one column of a table.
I want 2 columns named as mobile and email where those having values as 9000617634,balajirao@ziraff, respectively .
How to get in sql server.

see the below one.

```
mobile             Email
------             ------------
9100617634         balajirao1@ziaff.in
```

Comment: what version of sql server are you using? working with json data is supported from sql server 2016. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server

Comment: 2016 sql version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT 
case when [MOBILE/PHONE] like '[a-z]%' then null else [MOBILE/PHONE] end as [MOBILE/PHONE],
 case when ISNUMERIC(email)=0  then EMAIL  end as EMAIL
FROM
(
select 
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(RIGHT(right(left(AC.Communication,charindex('}',AC.Communication)),len(left(AC.Communication,charindex('}',AC.Communication))) - charindex(':',left(AC.Communication,charindex('}',AC.Communication)))),LEN(right(left(AC.Communication,charindex('}',AC.Communication)),len(left(AC.Communication,charindex('}',AC.Communication))) - charindex(':',left(AC.Communication,charindex('}',AC.Communication)))))-CHARINDEX(':',right(left(AC.Communication,charindex('}',AC.Communication)),len(left(AC.Communication,charindex('}',AC.Communication))) - charindex(':',left(AC.Communication,charindex('}',AC.Communication)))))),2,CHARINDEX(']',AC.Communication)),'"}','') AS [MOBILE/PHONE],
 REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(right(AC.Communication,charindex(':',reverse(AC.Communication))),LEN(right(AC.Communication,charindex(':',reverse(AC.Communication))))-charindex('}',reverse(right(AC.Communication,charindex(':',reverse(AC.Communication)))))),':"',' '),'"','') AS EMAIL

from DimAccountContact as AC

Comment: got required result for me based on some changes done to above answers

Answer (score 0):

U can Use Pivot Function to convert the row values to column,
Below is the Static Code for implementation

```
SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT
     columns_name
   FROM
      table_name
     ) M
   PIVOT (MAX(Key) FOR table_name IN (mobile ,Email))AS  P ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that was fun doing it the hard way :)

```
--initial string
declare @s1 varchar(1000) = (select '[{"key":"Mobile","value":"9100617634"},{"key":"Email","value":"balajirao1@ziaff.in"}]')

--selecting first part and second part of string
declare @mobile varchar(100) = (select right(left(@s1,charindex('}',@s1)-1),len(left(@s1,charindex('}',@s1))) - charindex(':',left(@s1,charindex('}',@s1)))-1))
declare @mail varchar(100) = (select right(@s1,charindex(':',reverse(@s1))-1))

--getting rid of extra characters
set @mobile = (right(@mobile, len(@mobile) - charindex(':',@mobile)))
set @mail = (left(@mail, len(@mail) - charindex('}',reverse(@mail))))


--getting rid of double quotes
set @mobile = replace(@mobile,'"','')
set @mail = replace(@mail,'"','')

--selecting data
select 
@mobile as Mobile,
@mail as Mail
```

Result is as following:

Mobile  Mail

9100617634  balajirao1@ziaff.in